# TSQL to search text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation as following

```
declare @vendor as table (vName varchar(max))
insert into @vendor
select *
from
(
    values
        ('Maccro'),
        ('Accro')
) t (one)

declare @transaction as table (descr varchar(max))
insert into @transaction
select *
from
(
    values
        ('recl Maccro something'),
        ('lrec Accro Maccro'),
        ('lrec Maccr0'),
        ('Maccro indeed'),
        ('ACCR Accro'),
        ('Raac else')
) t (one)
```

I want to run a query which will search each value from `@vendor` in each of the row values of `@transaction` and if that value is contained within `descr` returns 1 when the first value is matched.

So in my example, my desired result is following

```
| descr                 | doesContain |
| --------------------- | ----------- |
| recl Maccro something | 1           |
| lrec Accro Maccro     | 1           |
| lrec Maccr0           | 0           |
| Maccro indeed         | 1           |
| ACCR Accro            | 1           |
| Raac else             | 0           |
```

I tried doing this through writing a `CASE` statement but that means I need to manually write that for each of the vendors which is not possible cause vendor table is dynamic and compounding.

This is what I have tried to so far

```
select 
a.descr,
CASE WHEN a.descr like '%Maccro%' then 1 else 0 end [doesContain]
from @transaction a
```

Comment: So you don't want to search for words? You want `'foo'` to match `'foo'`, `'football'`, `'barfood'`, ... regardless of word boundaries.

Comment: I want `foo` to match only `foo` and not `football`

Comment: Then you'll need a better answer. That's easier with a better question. Are words _always_ separated by a single space, i.e. you never have `'Playing soccer (football),rugby and tennis.'`? Adding the unique separator (one space) to both strings will ensure a word match, i.e. `' ' + descr + ' ' like '% ' + vname + ' %'`. Alternatively you can use `String_Split()` to break the description into words, `join` them with the vendor names and `String_Agg()` to combine matches to answer your next question. If you have more punctuation to deal with then it gets harder. And it's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: Many thanks for this. This is amazimg. I did not know how to search word till you shared this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Select 
    a.descr,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * From @vendor b
                     where Charindex(b.Vname, a.descr) > 0)
              then 1 else 0 End [doesContain]
from @transaction a
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question which I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68747592/tsql-to-return-what-exists). Is it also possible to see on what value from `@vendor` tbl, `EXISTS` returns a match?

Comment: @smpa01 What if it matches more than one of them?

Comment: If it matches more than once, it is to return only the first value, i.e. `containsWhat` would return `Accro` for `lrec Accro Maccro`.