# TSQL to return what exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, window-functions

This is a follow-up question to this
[TSQL to search text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746536/tsql-to-search-text)

My situation is following

```
declare @vendor as table (vName varchar(max))
insert into @vendor
select *
from
(
    values
        ('Maccro'),
        ('Accro')
) t (one)

declare @transaction as table (descr varchar(max))
insert into @transaction
select *
from
(
    values
        ('recl Maccro something'),
        ('lrec Accro Maccro'),
        ('lrec Maccr0'),
        ('Maccro indeed'),
        ('ACCR Accro'),
        ('Raac else')
) t (one)
```

I can run the following query

```
Select 
    a.descr,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * From @vendor b
                     where Charindex(b.Vname, a.descr) > 0)
              then 1 else 0 End [doesContain]

from @transaction a
```

which returns the following

```
| descr                 | doesContain |
| --------------------- | ----------- |
| recl Maccro something | 1           |
| lrec Accro Maccro     | 1           |
| lrec Maccr0           | 0           |
| Maccro indeed         | 1           |
| ACCR Accro            | 1           |
| Raac else             | 0           |
```

But is it possible to see on what value it returns 1 for `doesContain`, i.e. on what value from `@vendor` table, `Exists` returns a match.

My desired output is following

```
| descr                 | doesContain | containsWhat |
| --------------------- | ----------- | ------------ |
| recl Maccro something | 1           | Maccro       |
| lrec Accro Maccro     | 1           | Accro        |
| lrec Maccr0           | 0           |              |
| Maccro indeed         | 1           | Maccro       |
| ACCR Accro            | 1           | Accro        |
| Raac else             | 0           |              |
```

Comment: `containsWhat ` for `'lrec Accro Maccro'` should be `'Maccro'` also.

Comment: It wasn't me, but my guess would be "lack of research" - you don't appear to have tried anything.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I did not know what to do to solve this problem. So that probably was seen as "lack of research"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT` join of `@transaction` to `@vendor` and `FIRST_VALUE()`  window function to get the 1st occurrence:

```
Select distinct
    a.descr,
    CASE WHEN b.Vname is not null then 1 else 0 End [doesContain],
    first_value(b.Vname) over (partition by a.descr order by Charindex(b.Vname, a.descr)) containsWhat 
from @transaction a left join @vendor b
on Charindex(b.Vname, a.descr) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e43a29de1ad3437bada60d7e22bf75b6).

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to get list of vendors for a transaction you may use  outer apply with string_agg function.

```
Select 
a.descr,
Case When v.list Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End,
v.list
From @transaction a Outer Apply
    (Select String_AGG(b.vName,', ') As list From @vendor b
     Where PatIndex(Concat('% ',b.Vname,' %'), a.descr) > 0 Or
           PatIndex(Concat(b.Vname,' %'), a.descr) > 0 Or
           PatIndex(Concat('% ',b.Vname), a.descr) > 0) v
```

Answer (score 1):

use a cross product between vendor and transaction then use charindex to see if the vendorname is in the descr.  if you have multiple vendors this approach work well.

```
declare @vendor as table (vName varchar(max))
insert into @vendor
select distinct *
from
(
values
    ('Maccro'),
    ('Accro')
) t (one)

declare @transaction as table (descr varchar(max))
insert into @transaction
select *
from
(
values
    ('recl Maccro something'),
    ('lrec Accro Maccro'),
    ('lrec Maccr0'),
    ('Maccro indeed'),
    ('ACCR Accro'),
    ('Raac else')
) t (one)

select trans.descr,vend.vName vName,
case when charindex(vend.vName,trans.descr)>0 then 1 else 0 end doesContain
from @transaction trans
cross apply @vendor vend
order by descr,vName
```

output

```
ACCR Accro  Accro   1
ACCR Accro  Maccro  0
Maccro indeed   Accro   0
Maccro indeed   Maccro  1
Raac else   Accro   0
Raac else   Maccro  0
lrec Accro Maccro   Accro   1
lrec Accro Maccro   Maccro  1
lrec Maccr0 Accro   0
lrec Maccr0 Maccro  0
recl Maccro something   Accro   0
recl Maccro something   Maccro  1
```